# How to prove congruence class is well-defined

Tags: number-theory

Let $m,n \in  \mathbb{Z}^+$ with $(m,n)=1$. Let $f :  \mathbb{Z}_{mn} \rightarrow \mathbb{Z}_m \times  \mathbb{Z}_n$ by, for all $a\in  \mathbb{Z}$ $f([a]_{mn}) = ([a]_m,[a]_n)$

Prove that $f$ is well-defined.

Let $m = 4$ and $n=7$. Find $a \in  \mathbb{Z}$ such that $f([a]_{28}) = ([3]_4,[5]_7)$

Now i did do a search and found a few questions on stack exchange that were similar but I did not fully understand there justification for the answers given hence the new question.

Comment: This is a ring-theoretic form of CRT = Chinese Remainder Theorem. Are you familiar with CRT in congruence form (or ring form)?

Comment: Not at all, and im not really familiar with linear interpolation as the answer suggested below.

Answer (score 1):

**Hints**:

1. Proving $f$ is well-defined amounts o proving that $\mathbf Z/mn\mathbf Z\longrightarrow \mathbf Z/m\mathbf Z$ is well defined, in other words that if $x'\equiv x\mod mn$, then  $x'\equiv x\mod m$.
2. Start from a Bézout's relation between the coprime moduli $m$ and $n$:
   $$um+vn=1,\quad m,n\in\mathbf Z.$$
   This relation implies that $vn\equiv 1\mod m$, $vn\equiv 0\mod n$ and $um\equiv 0\mod m$, $um\equiv 1\mod n$. To solve the system of  congruences
   \begin{cases}
   x\equiv\alpha\mod m,\\x\equiv\beta\mod n,
   \end{cases}
   think of linear interpolation.